# How to draw a network from a dataset reporting the labels of nodes of every link?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

I have a dataset in format `.txt` of a directed network, containing a matrix `A` of dimension `m x 2`, where each row gives the labels of two nodes showing a direct link.

For example, when the network has $4$ nodes, the matrix `A` could be

```
A = [1 2; 1 3; 2 1; 2 4; 3 2; 4 1; 4 2]
```

where the first row means that there is a link from `1` to `2`, the second row means that there is a link from `1` to `3`, etc.

Could you suggest me a way to draw the network specified by `A` in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Probably you can do: `DirectedEdge @@@ Import["text.txt", "Data"] // Graph`. Please take a look at all those symbols in documentation if there are doubts.

Comment: I guess you're aware that your line of code is NOT valid in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get a minimum involved in what you are planning to do and search for *"network"* inside *Mathematica*:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html

Then you want to construct a `Graph` so you go to:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphConstruction.html

and see: *`Graph` — construct a graph from vertices and edges*:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html

where the first example is:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So hey! Why not giving the same structure to `A`:

```
A = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2}
Graph[A]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Regarding the `Import` part (like Kuba [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48333/how-to-draw-a-network-from-a-dataset-reporting-the-labels-of-nodes-of-every-link/48336#comment144421_48333)):

```
mat = First@ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tVXqhVgD", "Data"]
```

> ```
> {{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{2,4},{3,2},{4,1},{4,2}}
> ```

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ mat]
```